# XNA - Keyboard text input

Tags: c#, .net, xna

Okay, so basically I want to be able to retrieve keyboard text. Like entering text into a text field or something. I'm only writing my game for windows.
I've disregarded using Guide.BeginShowKeyboardInput because it breaks the feel of a self contained game, and the fact that the Guide always shows XBOX buttons doesn't seem right to me either. Yes it's the easiest way, but I don't like it.

Next I tried using System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow. I created a class that inherited from it, and passed it the Games window handle, implemented the WndProc function to catch WM_CHAR (or WM_KEYDOWN) though the WndProc got called for other messages, WM_CHAR and WM_KEYDOWN never did. So I had to abandon that idea, and besides, I was also referencing the whole of Windows forms, which meant unnecessary memory footprint bloat.

So my last idea was to create a Thread level, low level keyboard hook. This has been the most successful so far. I get WM_KEYDOWN message, (not tried WM_CHAR yet) translate the virtual keycode with Win32 funcation MapVirtualKey to a char. And I get my text! (I'm just printing with Debug.Write at the moment)

A couple problems though. It's as if I have caps lock on, and an unresponsive shift key. (Of course it's not however, it's just that there is only one Virtual Key Code per key, so translating it only has one output) and it adds overhead as it attaches itself to the Windows Hook List and isn't as fast as I'd like it to be, but the slowness could be more due to Debug.Write.

Has anyone else approached this and solved it, without having to resort to an on screen keyboard? or does anyone have further ideas for me to try?

thanks in advance.

Question asked by Jimmy

> Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but why can't you use the XNA Keyboard and KeyboardState classes?

My comment:

> It's because though you can read keystates, you can't get access to typed text as and how it is typed by the user.

So let me further clarify. I want to implement being able to read text input from the user as if they are typing into textbox is windows. The keyboard and KeyboardState class get states of all keys, but I'd have to map each key and combination to it's character representation. This falls over when the user doesn't use the same keyboard language as I do especially with symbols (my double quotes is shift + 2, while american keyboards have theirs somewhere near the return key).

---

it seems my window hook was the way to go, just the reason I wasn't getting WM_CHAR is because the XNA message pump doesn't do translate message.

Adding TranslateMessage in whenever I received a WM`_`KEYDOWN message meant I got my WM_CHAR message, I then used this to fire a character typed event in my MessageHook class which my KeyboardBuffer class had subscribed to, which then buffers that to a text buffer :D (or StringBuilder, but the result is the same)

So I have it all working as I want.

Many thanks to Jimmy for a link to a very informative thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but why can't you use the XNA Keyboard and KeyboardState classes?

Comment: It's because though you can read keystates, you can't get access to typed text as and how it is typed by the user.

Comment: Ah I see. In the past, I've written a utility class for this purpose, similar to the one at http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=457783

Comment: Thanks, it seems my window hook was the way to go, just the reason I wasn't getting WM_CHAR is because the XNA message pump doesn't do translate message. I'll have a fiddle around and see what else I can get :)

Answer (score 9):

For adding a windows hook in XNA

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;

/* Author: Sekhat
 * 
 * License: Public Domain.
 * 
 * Usage:
 *
 * Inherit from this class, and override the WndProc function in your derived class, 
 * in which you handle your windows messages.
 * 
 * To start recieving the message, create an instance of your derived class, passing in the
 * window handle of the window you want to listen for messages for.
 * 
 * in XNA: this would be the Game.Window.Handle property
 * in Winforms Form.Handle property
 */

namespace WindowsHookExample
{
    public abstract class WindowsHook : IDisposable
    {
        IntPtr hHook;
        IntPtr hWnd;
        // Stored here to stop it from getting garbage collected
        Win32.WndProcDelegate wndProcDelegate;

        public WindowsHook(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            this.hWnd = hWnd;

            wndProcDelegate = WndProcHook;

            CreateHook();
        }

        ~WindowsHook()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        private void CreateHook()
        {

            uint threadId = Win32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero);

            hHook = Win32.SetWindowsHookEx(Win32.HookType.WH_CALLWNDPROC, wndProcDelegate, IntPtr.Zero, threadId);

        }

        private int WndProcHook(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, ref Win32.Message lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0)
            {
                Win32.TranslateMessage(ref lParam); // You may want to remove this line, if you find your not quite getting the right messages through. This is here so that WM_CHAR is correctly called when a key is pressed.
                WndProc(ref lParam);
            }

            return Win32.CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, ref lParam);
        }

        protected abstract void WndProc(ref Win32.Message message);

        #region Interop Stuff
        // I say thankya to P/Invoke.net.
        // Contains all the Win32 functions I need to deal with
        protected static class Win32
        {
            public enum HookType : int
            {
                WH_JOURNALRECORD = 0,
                WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK = 1,
                WH_KEYBOARD = 2,
                WH_GETMESSAGE = 3,
                WH_CALLWNDPROC = 4,
                WH_CBT = 5,
                WH_SYSMSGFILTER = 6,
                WH_MOUSE = 7,
                WH_HARDWARE = 8,
                WH_DEBUG = 9,
                WH_SHELL = 10,
                WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE = 11,
                WH_CALLWNDPROCRET = 12,
                WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13,
                WH_MOUSE_LL = 14
            }

            public struct Message
            {
                public IntPtr lparam;
                public IntPtr wparam;
                public uint msg;
                public IntPtr hWnd;
            }

            /// <summary>
            ///  Defines the windows proc delegate to pass into the windows hook
            /// </summary>                  
            public delegate int WndProcDelegate(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, ref Message m);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(HookType hook, WndProcDelegate callback,
                IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, ref Message m);

            [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string module);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "TranslateMessage")]
            public extern static bool TranslateMessage(ref Message m);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public extern static uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr window, IntPtr module);
        }
        #endregion

        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }

        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // Free managed resources here
            }
            // Free unmanaged resources here
            if (hHook != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Win32.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: The order of the members of that Message struct are incorrect and produce garbled results. They should be in this order: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644964(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I used the solution from this [gamedev.net post](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=457783) and it works great :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way, IMO, to have the `space`, `back`, `A-Z` and then the special chars `!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,)`. (Note, you need to import `System.Linq`) Here are the fields:

```
Keys[] keys;
bool[] IskeyUp;
string[] SC = { ")" , "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "("};//special characters
```

Constructor:

```
keys = new Keys[38];
Keys[] tempkeys;
tempkeys = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)).Cast<Keys>().ToArray<Keys>();
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < tempkeys.Length; i++)
{
    if (i == 1 || i == 11 || (i > 26 && i < 63))//get the keys listed above as well as A-Z
    {
        keys[j] = tempkeys[i];//fill our key array
        j++;
    }
}
IskeyUp = new bool[keys.Length]; //boolean for each key to make the user have to release the key before adding to the string
for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
    IskeyUp[i] = true;
```

And Finally, the update method:

```
string result = "";

public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    KeyboardState state = Keyboard.GetState();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (Keys key in keys)
    {
        if (state.IsKeyDown(key))
        {
            if (IskeyUp[i])
            {
                if (key == Keys.Back && result != "") result = result.Remove(result.Length - 1);
                if (key == Keys.Space) result += " ";
                if (i > 1 && i < 12)
                {
                    if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.RightShift) || state.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift))
                        result += SC[i - 2];//if shift is down, and a number is pressed, using the special key
                    else result += key.ToString()[1];
                }
                if (i > 11 && i < 38)
                {
                    if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.RightShift) || state.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift))
                       result += key.ToString();
                    else result += key.ToString().ToLower(); //return the lowercase char is shift is up.
                }
            }
            IskeyUp[i] = false; //make sure we know the key is pressed
        }
        else if (state.IsKeyUp(key)) IskeyUp[i] = true;
        i++;
    }
    base.Update(gameTime, otherScreenHasFocus, coveredByOtherScreen);
}
```

Hopefull this well help. I personally thought it was easier to use than the hooks, and this also can easily be modified for special results (such as shuffling the keys).

Comment: Only problem with this, is that it's not event based. So if the user types quicker than your update rate, key presses will be missed.

Comment: @Sekhat, if the Update method takes place every 16 ms, that's 60 updates per second. I highly doubt a user could type more than 60 characters per second (which would be 3600 chars per min). :) Hardly anyone can even type 700 CPM (see typing-speed-test.aoeu.eu/?lang=en) I'm in the 80th percentile and get 330 CPM.

Comment: If I press and release a key in under 16ms, your code will never register it. It's easier than it sounds, trust me.

Comment: @Sekhat, you are just speculating (Have you actually tried to do that?). I tried to press a key as to not make it register, but every keypress registered. Also, why would a user try to press a key that fast? Do they do that with `GamePad`s? Does there need to be a hook for a `gamepad` too to make it work? Also, note you accepted the answer that uses a `keyboardstate`.

Comment: Not at all speculating, I had that very issue when I initially developed something with the in built XNA stuff. edit: As for users pressing a key that fast, for me it just happened when typing out sentances when testing the initial typing code that used KeyboardState.

Answer (score 0):

This page is on top of  google result  about WM_CHAR interception in xna, so i leave here some note. Maybe this will be useful for other (if they will be able to understand my English =)) ).

I try code with windowshook from Sekhat, but seems there should be WH_GETMESSAGE passed to SetWindowsHookEx instead Win32.HookType.WH_CALLWNDPROC (only with WH_GETMESSAGE code lparaw will point to Win32.Message ).

Also there is sometime duplicated messages (with wparam 0).
(look here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644981%28v=VS.85%29.aspx 
something about PM_NOREMOVE/PM_REMOVE in WPARAM )

When i add something like this

```
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == 1)
    {
        Win32.TranslateMessage(ref lParam); 
        WndProc(ref lParam);
    }
```

wm_keypress wm_char duplication stopped (i supose 1 is PM_NOREMOVE or PM_REMOVE).

P.S.
nuclex variant now show 404 page, but can be viewed with webarchive.
nuclex variant works, but it cause broken mouseWheel processing from native XNA MouseState (on XNA 3.1) =(