# How to capture windows 7 touch events in XNA?

Tags: windows-7, xna, multi-touch

Anyone know how to capture windows 7 (not phone!) 
touch events in an XNA application ?
I really want to do this without rendering everything into a Form.
Any ideas ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle `WM_TOUCHUP`, `WM_TOUCHDOWN`, etc via `WndProc`.

There's a really nice and comprehensive article [available here](http://xna-uk.net/blogs/randomchaos/archive/2010/02/10/xna-and-windows-7-multi-touch.aspx), which provides code and explanation.

Comment: yes, and he does it by rendering to a form.
Which I am trying to avoid due to the big performance hit.

Comment: Sorry about that.. You could try hooking `WndProc` using the method from this answer (as far as I see there's no `Windows.Forms` reference so should be good to go!): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375316/xna-keyboard-text-input/647273#647273