# Convert numpad key input to his int value

Tags: c#, xna, keyboard

I need to get key input, and if it's one of the numpads 1-9, get it's int value.

for example if NumPad9 is pressed I need to get the value 9.

I have been working on it for an hour, can't seem to solve it.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
class Input
{
    private int[] Key = { 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3 };
    private Position[] Values;
    public Input()
    {
        Values = new Position[9];
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                Values[index++] = new Position(i, j);

    }
    public Position GetPos(int Key)
    {
        return Values[Key];
    }
    /*public Position ReadInput(KeyboardState Keyboard)
    {
     * Here is the function that I need to call, how can I check efficiently if one of the
     * Numpads 1-9 is pressed?
     * return GetPos(IntegerValue);
    }*/
}
```

The Position type just contains Row and Col int values.

Also, how can I check if only one key is pressed?

Comment: Look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375316/xna-keyboard-text-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you need, but should be something similar to this...

```
bool TryReadInput(out int Value)
{
    int Min = (int) Keys.D0;
    int Max = (int) Keys.D9;
    for (int k = Min; k<=Max; k++)
    {
         if (current_kb_state.IsKeyDown( (Keys) k) 
           && previous_kb_state.IsKeyUp( (Keys) k))
         { 
             value = k - Min;
             return true;
         }   
    }
    value = -1;
    return false;
}
```

if you need the col and row values:

```
col = (key+1) / 3;
row = (key+1) % 3;
```