# How do I get an exclamation point in KeyState?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I've been trying to implement a chat system in my game, so far I got it to accept strings of text and I'm trying to implement special characters such as periods, commas, and apostrophes.

For Example, this is how you normally get the period and comma:

```
            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.OemPeriod);
            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.OemComma);
```

However, I can't find any thing relating to the Exclamation point (!) in this kind of context.
I know I could just check if both the Shift and 1 keys are being pressed, but in this case if I try to do

```
            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift) && (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D1))
               text += "!";
               break;
```

It adds the exclamation point every time I press either Shift or the 1 key. **This Means That it makes Exclamation Point, even if the intended character was the 1**

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fiddled around in some Windows Forms for a bit to see if I could reproduce this problem. (I couldn't...) Understanding that you're using XNA, which, doesn't by default come with an easy way to input text **as the user typed it**, perhaps you need to relook into the way you're attempting to capture user input altogether. It seems a little much to program around capturing every key, including keys like comma, period, and so on.

Check out another question that was asked along the same vein [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375316/xna-keyboard-text-input).

Essentially **you're going to want to get a plugin or get a utility class to handle keyboard input**. In this [thread in particular](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/457783-xna-getting-text-from-keyboard/#entry4040153), they've got a `TranslateChar()` method, which will switch through several cases, including your beloved exclamation mark:

`case Keys.D1: return (shift) ? '!' : '1';`

Hopefully this information is helpful! Best of luck!