# Get raw mouse movement (not screen position)

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I've been using the xna Mouse class and the only way I've been able to get the mouse movement each frame is to reset the mouse to the centre of the screen each time and then measure the displacement before putting it back to the centre.  This seems awfully hackish, and my mouse supports a resolution of 5700dpi, which I'm mostly certainly not getting when xna returns an integer for the screen position.

Comment: No, that's exactly what I don't want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `Mouse.SetPosition` and measuring the offset isn't working for you, you'll need to use an API other than XNA.

**The API that you want to use is `WM_INPUT`.** This is a message you can receive by hooking the message loop. (Note: XNA's API is equivalent to `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, so don't use that.)

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418864(v=vs.85).aspx) has some introductory details about the API choices, and has some example code (in C++) for using it for mouse input.

If you're unfamiliar with the Windows message loop, perhaps start on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows). It is fundamentally a native (C/C++) API, so you'll have to do some work to use it from C#.

I don't have any code handy for doing this myself, but [here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/647273/165500) to someone hooking the message loop so they can handle `WM_CHAR`, that is perhaps a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I recently switched away from a MouseMove monstrosity myself and found this helpful.  However it seems SharpDX has already wrapped most of this in its [RawInput](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/n-sharpdx-rawinput) module, so that's mostly good enough for me.  Barring that, one can hook Windows.System.Forms' message loop by overriding [WndProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); WM_INPUT is message id 0x00FF; declaring unions in .NET is tricky, need [[StructLayout]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) attributes.